# Wordpress attach separate image gallery to post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need a image gallery attached to my posts but I don't want to have it in the text box. I want it in a separate div of my template.

Is there any free solution for that?

I know that the "Advanced Custom Fields" "Gallery Field" extension does exactly what I want but I don't want to spend 25€ for that.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can upload your photos just as mediafiles, attach them to your post, give them some common alt/caption/description and filter by this property in your code.
You don't have to insert your media files as gallery or standalone in text box.